# How to search Gmail with negation

Tags: gmail, search

The application I maintain sends error emails to me, which contain a build number and a description of the failure.  I want to be able to search for specific messages from specific builds but Gmail doesn't seem to handle this properly.  I have tried:

```
NullPointerException 12B -12A
```

to find emails for NullPointerExceptions that occurred in build 12B, and exclude those that came from build 12A.  This search returns all NullPointerExceptions that came from EITHER 12B or 12A.  I tried various grouping operators and nothing seems to work.

If I just search for 12B -12A it correctly doesn't show any 12A emails, but as soon as I add "NullPointerException" it starts finding all the NullPointerException emails ever.

Comment: Are all these terms in the body or subject of the message ?

Comment: The NullPointerException part is in both and the build numbers are only in the body.

Answer (score 2):

Try `(NullPointerException AND 12B) -12A`

Comment: That doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Import the set of email messages that you want to search in Mozilla Thunderbird. Install the *ImportExportTools* add-on and use it to export the messages locally to a searchable format. Now use whatever search tool you like, for instance `grep`, to search your local repository.

It's a bizarre and tedious solution, but hey it works. And there seems to be little else one can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by wrapping the `-` within literal quotes.

> NullPointerException 12B "-" 12A

or

> NullPointerException 12B "-12A"